# How can i set default post title when someone will go to add new post not placeholder, force to set at least 1 category and 3 tags

Tags: wordpress

i am trying to set default post title when someone will go to add new post, i tried this question [Wordpress set default title when creating a new custom post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831801/wordpress-set-default-title-when-creating-a-new-custom-post) but no solution. I am also trying to force 1 category select and at least 3 tags. If some one do not add 1 category then message will be displayed in the top of post title field not as javascript alert.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to add default title

```
function my_default_title_filter() {
    global $post_type;
    if ('post' == $post_type) {
        return 'My Filtered Title';
    }
}
add_filter('default_title', 'my_default_title_filter');
```

Also maybe you can use this plugin to force selecting a category and tags
https://wordpress.org/plugins/required-fields/

Comment: solved 50% thanks, actually i don't like to use plugin now